# rails < 4.0 "try" method throwing NoMethodError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, nomethoderror

Why is try throwing an error? Doesnt that defeat the whole purpose? Maybe its just in the console?

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :101 > User.first.try(:something)
NoMethodError: undefined method `something' for #<User:0x000001046ad128>
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activemodel-3.0.10/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:392:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/activerecord-3.0.10/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:46:in `method_missing'
    from (irb):101
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:44:in `start'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/railties-3.0.10/lib/rails/commands.rb:23:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

EDIT:

Thanks guys, now I get it.

Is there a way to do what I wanted without doing using `respond_to?`, such that `User.try(:something)` returns `nil` instead of throwing the error?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

## Rails 3

You misunderstand how `try` works, from the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.20/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

> **try(*a, &b)**
>   Invokes the method identified by the symbol method, passing it any arguments and/or the block specified, just like the regular Ruby `Object#send` does.
>
> Unlike that method however, a `NoMethodError` exception will not be raised and `nil` will be returned instead, if the receiving object is a `nil` object or `NilClass`.

And the version of [`try` that is patched into `NilClass`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try):

> **try(*args)**
>   Calling `try` on `nil` always returns `nil`.

So `try` doesn't ignore your attempt to call a non-existent method on an object, it ignores your attempt to call a method on `nil` and returns `nil` instead of raising an exception. The `try` method is just an easy way to avoid having to check for `nil` at every step in a chain of method calls.

---

## Rails 4

The behavior of `try` has changed in Rails 4 so now it:

> Invokes the public method whose name goes as first argument just like `public_send` does, except that if the receiver does not respond to it the call returns `nil` rather than raising an exception.

So now `try` takes care of both checks at once. If you want the Rails 3 behavior, there is [`try!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try-21):

> Same as `try`, but will raise a `NoMethodError` exception if the receiving [sic] is not `nil` and does not implemented [sic] the tried method.

Comment: This behaviour changed in Rails 4.0, `try` will now not raise if the method is missing, however, `try!` will raise if the method is missing. See https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/04998cd0c92a13332844d04145a4ede3184c7bd0

Comment: @TimonVonk: Thanks for the heads up, I've updated the answer to differentiate between Rails3 and Rails4.

Answer (score 8):

This is what try does

> Invokes the method identified by the symbol method, passing it any
>   arguments and/or the block specified, just like the regular Ruby
>   Object#send does. Unlike that method however, a NoMethodError
>   exception will not be raised and nil will be returned instead, if the
>   receiving object is a nil object or NilClass.

So, let's say you setup `@user` in your controller but you didn't instantiate it then `@user.try(:foo)
 => nil` instead of

```
@user.foo
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for nil:NilClass
```

The important point here is that try is an instance method.  It also [doesn't return nil if the object you try on isn't nil](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try#798-Doesn-t-return-nil-if-the-object-you-try-from-isn-t-nil-).

Comment: Oh, makes sense. Is there a function to do what I wanted?

Comment: `User.column_names.include?("name")` or `@u.attributes.has_key?("name")`

Comment: so i have to do a check for it first, there is no way to do this is one line? that would be a nice feature ;)

Answer (score 5):

I know this is old, but it may help somebody else, because this is the first thing that popped up when I Googled this issue.  I "borrowed" the code for **try** and implemented my own **try_method** method which acts just like **try**, except that it first checks to see if the method exists before calling **send**.  I implemented this in Object and put it in an initializer, and I can now call it on any object.

```
class Object
  # Invokes the method identified by _method_, passing it any
  # arguments specified, just like the regular Ruby <tt>Object#send</tt> does.
  #
  # *Unlike* that method however, a +NoMethodError+ exception will *not* be raised
  # if the method does not exist.
  #
  # This differs from the regular Ruby <tt>Object#try</tt> method which only
  # suppresses the +NoMethodError+ exception if the object is Nil
  #
  # If try_method is called without a method to call, it will yield any given block with the object.
  #
  # Please also note that +try_method+ is defined on +Object+, therefore it won't work with
  # subclasses of +BasicObject+. For example, using try_method with +SimpleDelegator+ will
  # delegate +try_method+ to target instead of calling it on delegator itself.
  #
  # ==== Examples
  #
  # Without +try_method+
  #   @person && @person.respond_to?(:name) && @person.name
  # or
  #   (@person && @person.respond_to?(:name)) ? @person.name : nil
  #
  # With +try_method+
  #   @person.try_method(:name)
  #
  # +try_method+ also accepts arguments and/or a block, for the method it is trying
  #   Person.try_method(:find, 1)
  #   @people.try_method(:collect) {|p| p.name}
  #
  # Without a method argument try_method will yield to the block unless the receiver is nil.
  #   @person.try_method { |p| "#{p.first_name} #{p.last_name}" }
  #--
  # +try_method+ behaves like +Object#send+, unless called on +NilClass+ or a class that does not implement _method_.
  def try_method(method=nil, *args, &block)
    if method == nil && block_given?
      yield self
    elsif respond_to?(method)
      __send__(method, *args, &block)
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end

class NilClass
  # Calling +try_method+ on +nil+ always returns +nil+.
  # It becomes specially helpful when navigating through associations that may return +nil+.
  #
  # === Examples
  #
  #   nil.try_method(:name) # => nil
  #
  # Without +try_method+
  #   @person && @person.respond_to(:children) && !@person.children.blank? && @person.children.respond_to(:first) && @person.children.first.respond_to(:name) && @person.children.first.name
  #
  # With +try_method+
  #   @person.try_method(:children).try_method(:first).try_method(:name)
  def try_method(*args)
    nil
  end
end
```