# Undefined Method Nil Class - Simple Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations, one-to-many, data-modeling

I have two simple models, `Artwork` and `Artist`. Inside my `artwork#index` view:

```
<% @artwork.each do |art| %>
    Title: <%= art.title %>
    Artist: <%= art.artist.fullname %>
<% end %>
```

I keep getting this error though:

```
undefined method `fullname' for nil:NilClass
```

It's a one-to-many association. In my `Artwork` Model:

```
class Artwork < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :artist
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :artist
end
```

Artist Model:

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :artworks

    def fullname
        "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
    end
end
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `artist_id` in your `artworks` table without `nil` values?

Comment: @Pavan I just realized that some of them in the index do have a `nil` value. How can I bypass this exception, or tell it to still render even if some of them have `nil` value?

Comment: This should work in that `<%= art.try(:artist).fullname %>` Can you check again and confirm? along with @Emu answer.

Comment: @Pavan I'm getting the same error. I also tried with `first_name`

Comment: I used this: `art.artist.fullname if art.artist.present?` and got it working. Would you say this is the simplest way? Or is there some other configuration I could do maybe in the model or controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
def fullname
    "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
end
```

In any of your `artworks` there is no `artist_id`. Check if `artist_id` contains `nil` value for any `artwork` or not.

use, `art.artist.present?`

Comment: same error again, I've even tried it with `first_name` (`<%= art.artist.first_name %>`) which is actually a column in the database.

Comment: In any of your `artworks` there is no `artist_id`. Check if `artist_id` contains `nil` value for any `artwork` or not.

Comment: I just realized that some of them in fact do have a nil value. How can I bypass this or tell it to print nothing if it comes across a nil value?

Comment: check if `art.artist.present?` or not.

Comment: I used this: `art.artist.fullname if art.artist.present?` and got it working. Would you say this is the simplest way? Or is there some other configuration I could do maybe in the model or controller?

Comment: pavan's `try` method is the simplest. But you should read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426808/rails-try-method-throwing-nomethoderror