# Does ActiveSupport's Object#try method work with Thor::CoreExt::HashWithIndifferentAccess?

Tags: ruby, activesupport, middleman, thor

I'm working on a Middleman (Ruby) site. There are data objects which are instances of `Thor::CoreExt::HashWithIndifferentAccess`. However, it seems whenever I call `try` that I get `nil`.

I see that `Thor::CoreExt::HashWithIndifferentAccess` takes advantage of `method_missing`. Does this break how `try` works? Is anyone able to replicate this?

**UPDATE:** Here's a simple example. I'm using [Middleman](https://middlemanapp.com/) which provides access to [data files](https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/data_files/).

```
# /data/people.yml
jane:
  name: Jane Doe
  age: 25
john:
  name: John Doe
  age: 25
```

Then in a template you have access to the `data.people` method which returns a `Thor::CoreExt::HashWithIndifferentAccess` instance:

```
data.people.inspect
 #=> {"jane"=>{"name"=>"Jane Doe", "age"=>25},"john"=>{"name"=>"John Doe", "age"=>25}}

data.people.class
 #=> Thor::CoreExt::HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Now when I call `try` on anything I get `nil`:

```
data.people.jane
 #=> {"name"=>"Jane Doe", "age"=>25}

data.people.try('jane')
 #=> nil

data.people.try(:jane)
 #=> nil

data.people.try(:something_that_does_not_exist)
 #=> nil

data.people.jane.try(:name)
 #=> nil
```

Comment: How specifically are you calling `try`? `Thor::CoreExt::HashWithIndifferentAccess.instance_method(:try).owner` says that `try` comes from `Object` and that's where ActiveSupports puts `try`.

Comment: @muistooshort, that's what's confusing. I don't get an undefined method error—only `nil` all the time. I'll add an example to the post here...

Comment: The behavior of `try` changed in Rails4 (http://stackoverflow.com/a/7426863/479863), not sure about the specifics of `Thor::CoreExt::HashWithIndifferentAccess` so I'm just commenting.

Comment: Good to know. Thank you.